# Why additional queries are fired while persisting an entity having one-to-many relationship with other entity?

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

Example: 1 country has list of associated states(suppose 2).
when I persist country object following queries are fired by Hibernate:

```
insert into MyCountry (name, id) values (?, ?)
insert into MyState (name, country_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
insert into MyState (name, country_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
update MyState set country_id=? where id=?
update MyState set country_id=? where id=?
```

Why seperate update queries are fired where country_id could have been added in :

```
insert into MyState (name, country_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Could you post your mappings, and code that persists these objects? Is `cascade` set from country to state?

Comment: Mapping:@OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id",nullable = false)
    private List<State> states;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Hibernate `inverse` property:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/

> **What is “inverse” ?**
>
> This is the most confusing keyword in Hibernate, at least i took quite
>   a long time to understand it. The “inverse” keyword is always declare
>   in one-to-many and many-to-many relationship (many-to-one doesn’t has
>   inverse keyword), it means which side is responsible to take care of
>   the relationship. “inverse”, should change to “relationship owner”?
>
> In Hibernate, only the “relationship owner” should maintain the
>   relationship, and the “inverse” keyword is created to defines which
>   side is the owner to maintain the relationship. However the “inverse”
>   keyword itself is not verbose enough, I would suggest change the
>   keyword to “relationship_owner“.
>
> In short, inverse=”true” means this is the relationship owner, and
>   inverse=”false” (default) means it’s not.

Depending on the "relationship owner" Hibernate decides weather to make an update or not.

Comment: How to specify inverse with JPA annotations?